How to specify a bearer token authorization header to a VectorTileSource url request?
I was looking to use an Azure Maps VectorTileSource to render some custom vector tiles hosted on my server.  The server API expects an authorization header but the VectorTileSourceOptions only support a url to supply the template request for the tile required.
I get that the SDK supports automatic insertion of the header for Azure Urls when using the placeholder {azMapsDomain} but in my case I need to add my own authentication header.
I can't see any way to access the underlying http request so how can I specify my own dynamic bearer token?

I missed this answer but it is still relevant credentials-for-microsoft-maps-tilesource-callback.
Specifically with Azure Maps the tranformRequest callback mentioned is part of ServiceOptions.
